# Codebehind function not being called from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html-table, code-behind, pager

Probably a "doh" moment, but can't get this codebehind function to fire. In fact debugging shows it's not even being called, which may be indicative when finally displayed on the web page, one only sees:

```
<table id="dnn_ctr422_ViewPloads_PagerTable">....
```

Notice the missing "style". ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//aspx code
<table id="PagerTable" style="<%# GetPagerStyle() %>" runat="server">
   <tr>
   <td> 
      <asp:DataPager ID="PloadPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="PloadListView" OnPreRender ="PloadPager_PreRender" PageSize="20" >

//code behind      
protected String GetPagerStyle( )
    {
        return "background-color:" + (String)Settings["TableBackgroundColor"];
    }
```

Comment: No didn't call page.databind. I may well be using the wrong syntax here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you show it is not clear why it isn't run. It is possible that you run against a version that is not equal to your source, but I assume you already tried a full rebuild.

Know that you can set breakpoints in the ASPX page as well. But my hunch is that if this isnt't called, more isn't called. Have you tried breaking on `Page_Load` or `Page_PreRender`?

Another possibility is that your `PagerTable` object is changed by other code prior to `GetPagerStyle` being called. In that case, if the style-attribute is altered before it is run may yield this problem. A workaround and to find out whether you actually *can* set the style is to do the following in Page_Load:

```
// correction courtesy of Tim Schmelter ;)
PagerTable.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, 
    (String)Settings["TableBackgroundColor"]);
```

EDIT: Note, as others have pointed out, the following should also work (tried it, as there was some controversy, see other answers):

```
<table id="PagerTable" style="<%= GetPagerStyle() %>">
```

However, note that I removed the `runat="server"`. That means, you cannot use it from the code-behind anymore. I'm just assuming you're not doing anything else with this control in the code-behind, so whether this works for your situation I don't know.

Comment: Yes other functions are being hit in the debugger (There is much more to aspx page then this snippet). I suspect I'm just not using the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Have you called `Page.DataBind` since `<%#...` is a binding expression?

[inline asp.net tags... sorting them all out](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)

Apart from that, you can always set this stuff from codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PagerTable.Style.Add("background-color", (String)Settings["TableBackgroundColor"]);
}
```

Comment: Good of you to point out the binding expression, that's probably what the OP needs to change.

Comment: It's technically not a binding...then how to structure the function or should I just take the page_load method?

Comment: @Gio: It **is** a binding expression and it works only for databound controls implicitely. For all others you need to call `control.DataBind()` or simply `Page.DataBind()`(of course from codebehind). I would prefer the codebehind approach since you're already using it. Don't lump together gui and logic. Your `GetPagerStyle` approach is already hardlinking the function with this page and not very reusable(apart from copy/paste).

Comment: @Tim: so you recommend using page_load approach?

Comment: @Gio: Page_Load or Page_Init, you can decide. And with setting the [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.style%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) directly.

Comment: @Tim: you and Abel both gave me the page_load answer but he was first off the mark. But you were a great help if thats any consolation...(how does anybody get 21.7K points anyway..?) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gio: Abel only suggested to set a breakpoint in page_load to see where the problem is. I suggested to use either `Page.DataBind` in page_load since you've used a binding expression or to use page_load to apply your style via `control.Style.Add()`. Both would work: Edit: I've just seen that Abel also suggested to call `PagerTable.Style = GetPagerStyle();`.  Since your method returns a string and [`PagerTable.Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.style%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a `CssStyleCollection` this won't work.

Comment: Tim, thanks for pointing out my error, fixed now. +1 for your answer though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace # with = in your code,

`style="<%=GetPagerStyle()%>"` should work fine.

Comment: Tried that already .. you end up with < table style="&lt;%= GetPagerStyle() %>"> in the view...

Comment: @CanYener: `<%= %>` is a shortened for `Response.Write()` and is never valid as an attribute, for any server tag.

Comment: If you do not need your table in code behind, you can remove runat attribute and try again, as i noticed now, your table has runat="server" attribute, so your method is not a scriptlet anymore, it's just a plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<%= GetPagerStyle() %>
```

Comment: I don't think that this works,`<%= %>` is a shortened for `Response.Write()` and is never valid as an attribute, for any server tag.